# Importing very large sqlite table to BigQuery

Tags: sqlite, google-bigquery

I have a relatively large SQLite table (5 million rows, 2GB) which I'm trying to move to Google BigQuery. The easy solution, which I've used for other tables in the db, was to use something like SQLite Manager (the Firefox extension) to export to CSV, but this fails with what I'd imagine is an out of memory error when trying to export the table in question. I'm trying to think of the best way to approach this, and have come up with the following:

1. Write something that will manually write a single, gigantic CSV. This seems like a bad idea for many reasons, but the big ones are that one of the fields is text data which will inevitably screw things up with any of the delimiters supported by BQ's import tools, and I'm not sure that BQ could even support a single CSV that big
2. Write a script to manually export everything to a series of CSVs, like ~100k rows each or something--the main problem being that this will then require importing 50 files
3. Write everything to a series of JSONs and try to figure out a way to deal with it from there, same as above
4. Try to import it to MySQL and then do a mysqldump which apparently can be read by BQ
5. Use Avro, which seems like the same as #2 except it's going to be in binary so it'll be harder to debug when it inevitably fails

I also have some of this data on a local ElasticSearch node, but I couldn't find any way of migrating that to BQ either. Does anyone have any suggestions? Most of what I've found online has been trying to get things out of BQ, not put things in.

Comment: write a script that does a 5 then 100 lines of sample try that with bigquery, either CSV, JSON, (recommended) Avro as you wish. 2GB is not big, the uncompressed limit on BigQuery is 5TB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(2) is not a problem. BQ can import up to 10k files per import job.

Also, BQ can also import very large CSV/JSON/AVRO files, as long as the input can be sharded (text based formats are not compressed, CSV files without quoted new lines).

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#import for more.